# RIAK - Time Query

Tags: mapreduce, riak

Is it possible to search for records in RIAK based on time intervals? Such as pulling out the most recent records for the past 7 days.

Ie, from MySQL:

```
WHERE DATE(edit_date) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a 2i index to record the edit time for each record. Add these as UNIX timestamps. Then it's simple to query between two integers when looking up records.

Comment: Thanks. Tested this and it works. Use a RANGE 2i search.

Comment: Yup. The actual syntax will vary depending what library you're using to connect to Riak.